# how to plot file contains many columns and column header using gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have some data file like this:

```
Id a1 a2 a3
1  1  2  3 
2  2  3  4 
3  2  3  4
```

But I don't know the exact number of column, but I can get it into variable with shell. And I want to plot the data file, the first column as the x-axis and the others as the y-axis in one picture and the column header as the title for line.like this:

[image]

How to plot in gnuplot? Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

Consider this example

**colhead.gp**:

```
plot for [i=2:n+1] 'colhead.dat' u 1:i w lp title columnheader(i)
```

**colhead.dat**:

```
Id a1 a2 a3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  4
3  2  3  4
```

To get parameter from the shell:

```
gnuplot -persist -e "n=4" colhead.gp
```

Comment: I think you want "n=4" as the input if you want the for loop to pick up all columns.