# gnuplot not recognizing plot for syntax

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I am trying to use the for syntax for multiple columns.

I have a data file colhead.dat:

```
Id a1 a2 a3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  4
3  2  3  4
```

Following the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525615/429850, I do

```
gnuplot>  plot for [i=2:5] 'colhead.dat' u 1:i w lp title columnheader(i)
                    ^
         ':' expected
```

How do i write the for loop? Here's the gnuplot version header

```
Version 4.2 patchlevel 6
last modified Sep 2009
System: Linux 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For-loops have been implemented in version 4.6 of gnuplot, and there was nothing like loops in the versions before. So you have to update your version!

---

Edit: As Christoph mentioned, first `for` functionality was introduced in 4.4. However, 4.2 is too old.

Comment: Actually, `plot for` was introduced in 4.4. Only `do for` was introduced later with 4.6 ;)